# Google Maps JavaScript API v3: getDetails(request, callback) for multiple places

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, request

I have implemented Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to contrive a custom store locator for my company's website. Let me start by saying that the code I have works for the **two** stores, but it would not be efficient or feasible if I added any more stores because of the "hacky" code used to make it work.

I am using the Google Maps Places Library to send "place details" requests to Google using the `getDetails()` method. On the callback, I am receiving the `InfoWindow` information *(name, address, location)* for each of my store locations.

I create a marker for each place, then use `google.maps.event.addListener` to coordinate the Place, Marker, and InfoWindow objects. **This is where I encounter problems.** The *place details requests* are not always received in the same order they are sent which throws off the indexing of my buttons that have a `data-marker` attribute set to 0 and 1, respectively, to correlate to the map markers.

*Is there anyway to delay the second request until the first is finished? or write the script in a way that maintains ordinal integrity?*

The first snippet of code below is my event handler to bind the `click` listener to each button using the `.place.placeId` property of the marker rather than the **preferred technique** of using the index of the `markers` array (the `markers` array holds the *place details* for the two stores).

***None of the demos or examples in the Google Maps API documentation (Places Library) delineate the procedure for multiple places. Any tips, resources, or suggestions will be much appreciated***

> Website: http://m.alliancepointe.com/locate.html

**Event Handler**

```
 $(".loc-btn").on('click', function () {
        var me = $(this).data('marker');
        var place1 = markers[0].place.placeId;
        var myIndex = me == place1 ? 0 : 1;
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[myIndex], 'click');
    });
```

---

**Full JS**

```
var markers = [];
var map;
var infowindow;
var service;

function initialize() {
    var index;
    var daddr;
    var idVA = 'ChIJKezXgqmxt4kRXrAnqIwIutA';
    var geoVA = '38.80407,-77.062881/Alliance+Pointe,+LLC';

    var idDC = 'ChIJDQlqOLG3t4kRqDU3uNoy4hs';
    var geoDC = '38.90188,-77.049161/Alliance+Pointe,+LLC';

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        center: {lat: 38.90188, lng: -77.049161},
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        mapOptions);

    var request = [
        {placeId: idVA, location: {lat: 38.80407, lng: -77.062881}},
        {placeId: idDC, location: {lat: 38.90188, lng: -77.049161}}
    ];

    var office = [
        "Main Office",
        "Principal Office"
    ];

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    for (var i = 0; i < request.length; i++) {

        service.getDetails(request[i], function (placeResult, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                var id = placeResult.place_id;
                var location = placeResult.geometry.location;
                var trimAddr = placeResult.formatted_address.split(", ");

                var image = {
                    url: 'images/icons/AP-marker_large.png',
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 54)
                };
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    place: {
                        placeId: id,
                        location: location
                    },
                    icon: image,
                    title: "Get directions"
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    if (id == idVA) {
                        index = 0;
                        daddr = geoVA;
                        trimAddr[0] = "1940 Duke St #200";
                    } else {
                        index = 1;
                        daddr = geoDC;
                        trimAddr[0] = "2200 Pennsylvannia Ave NW";
                    }
                    infowindow.setContent('<div class="info-window title">' + placeResult.name + "</div><div class='info-window sub-title'>" + office[index] + '</div><div class="info-window">' + trimAddr[0] + '<br>' + trimAddr[1] + ", " + trimAddr[2] + '</div><div class="info-window direction-div"><div class="direction-icon"></div><a class="google-link save-button-link" target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/' + daddr + '">Get Directions</a></div>');
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });

                markers.push(marker);
                //bounds.extend(location);
            }
        });
    }

    if (!bounds.isEmpty()) {
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    $(".loc-btn").on('click', function () {
        var me = $(this).data('marker');
        var place1 = markers[0].place.placeId;
        var myIndex = me == place1 ? 0 : 1;
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[myIndex], 'click');

        //console.log("PlaceId = " + me);
        //console.log("Adj index = " + myIndex);
        //console.log("0:VA array index = " + markers[0].place.placeId);
        //console.log("1:DC array index = " + markers[1].place.placeId);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
        $.mobile.loading("hide");
        $(".loc-btn").prop("disabled",false);
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

---

**HTML: Map & Buttons**

```
<div data-role="content" class="full-width">

        <figure id="map"></figure>

        <div class="loc-btn-set">
            <button disabled data-role="none" data-theme="a" data-marker="ChIJKezXgqmxt4kRXrAnqIwIutA" class="loc-btn nightly-button">VA <span>- Alexandria</span></button>
            <button disabled data-role="none" data-theme="b" data-marker="ChIJDQlqOLG3t4kRqDU3uNoy4hs" class="loc-btn nightly-button">DC <span>- Washington</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Radar Search example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-radar-search) uses a `getDetails` for each marker returned (up to 200).

Comment: @geocodezip - I have my two stores saved in the  `requests` array. The problem is that when I request the JSON place data and create the marker for each store/place,  the data is not received in the order in which it was sent...so the index of the `requests` array does not coordinate with the `data-marker` index of the external buttons. (e.g `request[0] = VA location`, VA location `button` has `data-markers = 0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest approach based on the given code would be to add the click-handler for the buttons inside the `getDetails`-callback.

Add this after the creation of the `marker`:

```
            $('.loc-btn[data-marker="'+id+'"]').click(function(){
              google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click');
            });
```

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Molle, this does the trick. This is my first "project" using the GMv3 API. If I were to scale this up (say 100 stores), would you recommend another approach or code design from what used here? Moreover, do most large enterprises save this `place data` in a local array or json object in advance?...it seems like an organizational disaster to try to send and receive 100 requests all-while rendering the page.

Comment: I would store the entire data in a single object instead of these multiple variables(office,geoVA,idVA etc.) . The issue with storing the place-data basically is that it's not allowed to store data returned by the places-API. But when all these places are stores of your company you should be able to get the data without the places-API(usually somebody in your company has sended the place-data to google, so when the data for your your stores are known in your company you can store them and display the markers/details without requesting the places-API)

Comment: @Molle What you are saying makes perfect sense. So basically, I can save the 2 JSON objects (i.e what I am needlessly requesting from the Places API) on my local server and just populate the markers using these objects, rather than making request for the data.....strangely, this concept didn't come to mind when I originally wrote this code but after hearing you mention this, I can't believe I wasted the time trying to make this work. I had complete access to the JSON data from google from the start...just never thought about storing it. JSON is not my cup of tea! lol.